# Stress-Energy Tensor Integral Identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm attempting to work a problem in Schutz's *A First Course in General Relativity*, and I'm running into something curious with tensor indices. The problem states:

> Use the Identity $T^{\mu\nu}_{,\nu}=0$ to prove the following results for a bounded system (i.e. a system for which $T^{\mu\nu}=0$ outside a bounded region of space):
>
> (a) $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int T^{0\alpha}d^3x=0$
>
> (b) $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\int T^{00}x^ix^jd^3x=2\int T^{ij}d^3x$
>
> (c) $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\int T^{00}(x^ix_i)^2d^3x=4\int T^i_ix^jx_jd^3x+8\int T^{ij}x_ix_jd^3x$

The first two I managed to figure out, but the third I can't quite manage.

**My attempt at a solution:**

I begin by taking one of the time derivatives inside of the integral, and making use of the stress-energy conservation identity,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int T^{00}_{,0}(x^ix_i)^2d^3x=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int -T^{0k}_{,k}(x^ix_i)^2d^3x.
$$

I then notice that

$$
(T^{0k}(x^ix_i)^2)_{,k}=T^{0k}_{,k}(x^ix_i)^2+T^{0k}[(x^ix_i)^2]_{,k},
$$

so that the integral becomes

$$
-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int (T^{0k}(x^ix_i)^2)_{,k}-T^{0k}[(x^ix_i)^2]_{,k}d^3x.
$$

The first term in the integrand is a spatial gradient and thus, by Gauss' law, can be converted into a surface integral of $T^{0k}(x^ix_i)^2$. But taking the Gaussian surface around the bounded system, we find that the stress-energy tensor vanishes, and so the integral is reduced to

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int T^{0k}[(x^ix_i)^2]_{,k}d^3x=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int T^{0k}2(x^ix_i)(x^i_{,k}x_i+x^ix_{i,k})d^3x.
$$

Using the fact that $x^i_{,k}=\delta^i_k$ and $x_{i,k}=(x^j\eta_{ij})_{,k}=x^j_{,k}\eta_{ij}=\eta_{ik}$, the integral becomes

$$
2\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int T^{0k}x^i_{,k}x^i(x_i)^2+T^{0k}x_{i,k}(x^i)^2x_id^3x=2\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int T^{0i}x^i(x_i)^2+T^0_i(x^i)^2x_id^3x.
$$

Repeating the above steps with the second time derivative (bringing it into the integral, applying the conservation identity and the product rule, then using Gauss' law), I obtain

$$
2\int T^{ik}(x^i_{,k}(x_i)^2+2x^ix_ix_{i,k})+T^k_i(2x^ix^i_{,k}x_i+(x^i)^2x_{i,k})d^3x.
$$

Cleaning up a bit, it becomes

$$
2\int T^{ii} x_ix_i+2T^i_ix^ix_i+2T^i_ix^ix_i+T_{ii}x^ix^id^3x=4\int T^{ii}x_ix_id^3x+8\int T^i_ix^ix_id^3x,
$$

where I have used $T_{kl}x^kx^l=T_{kl}x_m\eta^{km}x_n\eta^{ln}=T^{mn}x_mx_n$.

Aside from the obvious fact that all my indices are the same (it seems to me that I shouldn't be able to switch out one pair of 'dummy' $i$s in a term without switching all of them), the 4 and the 8 are attached to the wrong integrals. Is this due to a mis-handling of indices, or some other mistake?

Comment: Something about your notation: too many $i$s. You should not have more than two $i$s in an expression at one time. Switch it up and use $j$s or other letters. It's tricky to read otherwise. I got $\partial_k(x_ix^i)^2=4(x_ix^i)x_k$. There should only be one term, but I'm not sure if that's your source of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
$$I=\partial^2_t\int d^3x\,T^{00}x^4=-\partial_t\int d^3x\,(\partial_kT^{k0})x^4$$
where $x^2\equiv x_ix^i$. Product rule:
$$(\partial_kT^{k0})x^4=\partial_k(T^{k0}x^4)-T^{k0}\partial_k x^4$$
The first term is a boundary term and in the second one $\partial_k x^4=4x^2x_k$. Thus
$$I=4\partial_t\int d^3x\,T^{k0}x^2x_k=-4\int d^3x\,(\partial_j T^{jk})x^2x_k$$
The integrand is
$$(\partial_j T^{jk})x^2x_k=\partial_j(T^{jk}x^2x_k)-T^{jk}(\partial_j x^2)x_k-T^{jk}x^2\partial_jx_k=\partial_j(T^{jk}x^2x_k)-2T^{jk}x_jx_k-Tx^2$$
where $T\equiv T^i_{\;i}$. Thus
$$I=4\int d^3x\,(2T^{jk}x_jx_k+Tx^2)$$
which is the desired result. I'll leave you to figure out where you went wrong, comment if you need help.

Comment: Aha! I see my mistake! Whereas I was differentiating the $x^ix_i$ factor as $[(x^ix_i)^2]_{,k}=2(x^ix_i)(x^i_{,k}x_i+x^ix_{i,k})$, I was ignoring the fact that the repeated indices mean it's a SUM. That is, $x^ix_i=x^0x_0+x^1x_1+x^2x_2+x^3x_3$. And since $x^i=x_i$ for spatial indices, $[(x^ix_i)^2]_{,k}=2(x^ix_i)(2x_k)=4x^2x_k$. Thanks!

Comment: Don't write $2(x^ix_i)(x^i_{,k}x_i+x^ix_{i,k})$! Too many $i$s! Write instead $2(x^jx_j)(x^i_{,k}x_i+x^ix_{i,k})$.

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right. I'm still trying to get used to when it's okay to switch the indices up.